# Name of the notation where number is expressed as a sum

Tags: notation, terminology

I have the following general form of a number:

[image]

Does this notation have a name?

Here is the example of using the form:

[image]

Comment: Where do the $b_i$ and $q$ live? It looks like a Laurent series because you have negative exponents. But in the theory of modular forms, when one writes down a power series expansion of a modular form in a neighborhood of infinity, the natural variable to use is $q = e^{2\pi I z}$ for a complex variable $z$, which is often referred to as a $q$-expansion. If $q$ is a prime, then this could be a $q$-adic representation of an integer $N$... In so many words, this notation could have many names depending on the context

Comment: Updated my question with the example

Comment: oh, you are writing numbers in a base $q$ decimal expansion

Comment: Is this the name of the notation - 'base q decimal expansion'? But it can be as well applied to the binary, so the word `decimal` is probably not belongs here

Comment: That is what I would call it. I typically reserve "$q$-adic" for $q$ a prime, but that might just be because I like number theory...

Comment: May I drop the `decimal` word? `base q number expansion` - does it sound right?

Comment: You could say that this is the "base $q$ expansion of the number $N$". You can say whatever you like. I don't typically hear people say "number expansion" though - either "decimal expansion" or simply "expansion" is what I am familiar with.

Comment: I see, ok, thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think "digital expansion" would be miss understood or objected to.  The linguists might think "decimal" implies "10" but I think mathematicians accept "decimal" means an expansion with an unspecified numeric base.  But "digital expansion" would work for me.  "q-adic" seems a bit technical and obscure and implies more theortically advanced abstract mathematics  IMO.  I think a layman would be intimidated.

Comment: @fleablood, thanks, maybe I'll use `digital expansion that`, however `base q expansion of the number N` is pretty good

Comment: Actually "base q expansion" is darned near perfect.  I think you can omit "decimal" if it bugs you (as it does me as well).

Comment: @fleablood, yeah, thanks for you feedback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is “[radix $q$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix)” or “base $q$” representation of numbers.  Your example ($12.625$) is written in radix-10 notation.

In radix-$q$ representation, the series is finite on the left (for positive powers of $q$) but potentially infinite on the right (for negative powers of $q$).  This is what you wrote in your question.

The term “$q$-adic” is probably not appropriate here; that usually refers to a system with *different* numbers, unlike the conventional ones, in which the series is bounded on the right but potentially infinite on the left.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the $q-$adic development or representation of $N$

Comment: thanks, I've googled it and can't seem to find any mentioning of this `q-adic` phrase, only `p-adic`. I'd like to mention this name for the notation in my blog post, but I also would like to include a reference to some resource explaining it.

Comment: @Maximus Just as $b_3\cdot q^3 + b_2\cdot q^2 + b_1\cdot q^1 + b_0\cdot q^0$ means the same as  $b_3\cdot p^3 + b_2\cdot p^2 + b_1\cdot p^1 + b_0\cdot p^0$, except with $q$ instead of $p$, so too do $q$-adic and $p$-adic mean the same.

Comment: @Maximus I've chosen $q$ cause you've chosen $q$. As pointed out by MJD, it's the same thing. If you write it down with $z$, it will be $z-$ adic.

Comment: @Thomas, yeah, I got it, thanks